# Sort strings with a specific letter order with Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, cpan

I'm trying to sort lists of names with Perl with a specific letter order to perform some special features.
The sorting would be working the same way as `sort { $a cmp $b }` but with a different succession of letters.
For example, ordering with the arbitrary character order **"abdrtwsuiopqe987654" ...**

I tried to deal with `sort { $a myFunction $b }` but I'm newbie with Perl and I don't see how to organize correctly `myFunction` to get what I want.

- Is there a specific function (a package) which provide this functionnality?
- Do you have an example of a custom sorting function dealing with strings ?
- Do you know how (or in which source file) is the `cmp` function implemented with Perl to see how it works ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is probably the fastest<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
sub my_compare($$) {
    $_[0] =~ tr{abdrtwsuiopqe987654}{abcdefghijklmnopqrs}r
       cmp
    $_[1] =~ tr{abdrtwsuiopqe987654}{abcdefghijklmnopqrs}r
}

my @sorted = sort my_compare @unsorted;
```

Or if you want something more dynamic, the following might be the fastest<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
my @syms = split //, 'abdrtwsuiopqe987654';
my @map; $map[ord($syms[$_])] = $_ for 0..$#syms;

sub my_compare($$) {
    (pack 'C*', map $map[ord($_)], unpack 'C*', $_[0])
       cmp
    (pack 'C*', map $map[ord($_)], unpack 'C*', $_[1])
}

my @sorted = sort my_compare @unsorted;
```

We could compare character by character, but that will be *far* slower.

```
use List::Util qw( min );

my @syms = split //, 'abdrtwsuiopqe987654';
my @map; $map[ord($syms[$_])] = $_ for 0..$#syms;

sub my_compare($$) {
    my $l0 = length($_[0]);
    my $l1 = length($_[1]);
    for (0..min($l0, $l1)) {
       my $ch0 = $map[ord(substr($_[0], $_, 1))];
       my $ch1 = $map[ord(substr($_[1], $_, 1))];
       return -1 if $ch0 < $ch1;
       return +1 if $ch0 > $ch1;
    }

    return -1 if $l0 < $l1;
    return +1 if $l0 > $l1;
    return 0;
}

my @sorted = sort my_compare @unsorted;
```

---

1. Technically, it can be made faster using GRT.

   ```
    my @sorted =
       map /\0(.*)/s,
       sort
       map { tr{abdrtwsuiopqe987654}{abcdefghijklmnopqrs}r . "\0" . $_ }
       @unsorted;
   ```
2. Technically, it can be made faster using GRT.

   ```
    my @sorted =
       map /\0(.*)/s,
       sort
       map { ( pack 'C*', map $map[ord($_)], unpack 'C*', $_ ) . "\0" . $_ }
       @unsorted;
   ```

---

`cmp` is implemented by the `scmp` operator.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$x cmp $y'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <#> gvsv[*x] s
4  <#> gvsv[*y] s
5  <2> scmp[t3] vK/2
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
```

The `scmp` operator is implemented by the `pp_scmp` function in [`pp.c`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/pp.c), which is really just a wrapper for `sv_cmp_flags` in [`sv.c`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/sv.c) when `use locale;` isn't in effect. `sv_cmp_flags` either uses C library function [`memcmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) or a UTF-8 aware version (depending on the type of scalar).

Comment: Should probably cache those transliterations, or at least make a note of the repeated computation that would occur if there were duplicates.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, I don't think the gains will be that great, but I've added GRT solutions.

Comment: Comparing character by character make exactly what I want. Nice answer !

Comment: Why? It's probably 100x slower!

Answer (score 1):

```
use Sort::Key qw(keysort);
my @sorted = keysort { tr/abdrtwsuiopqe987654/abcdefghijklmnopqrs/r } @data;
```

Or in older perls not supporting the `r` flag in `tr/.../.../r`

```
my @sorted = keysort { my $key = $_;
                       $key =~ tr/abdrtwsuiopqe987654/abcdefghijklmnopqrs/;
                       $key } @data;
```

You can also create an specialized sort subroutine for that kind of data as follows:

```
use Sort::Key::Maker 'my_special_sort',
                     sub { tr/abdrtwsuiopqe987654/abcdefghijklmnopqrs/r },
                     qw(string);

my @sorted = my_special_sort @data;
my @sorted2 = my_special_sort @data2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ikegami's answer, in the "if you want something more dynamic" solution, the comparison function seems incorrect. The following worked for me:

```
sub my_compare_orig($$) {
    (pack 'C*', map $map[$_], unpack 'C*', $_[0])
      cmp
    (pack 'C*', map $map[$_], unpack 'C*', $_[1]);
}
```

I removed the `ord()` call, because that's what `unpack` does; the index into $map is the character value.